# Value in ReadCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In Dynamo db, I have a alarm named TableName-ReadCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm. In this threshold is,

```
Threshold:The condition in which the alarm will go to the ALARM state.ConsumedReadCapacityUnits >= 6,000 for 5 datapoints within 5 minutes
Statistic: SamplesSum
Metric Name: ConsumedReadCapacityUnits
```

What does this 6000, represent? My provisioned read capacity for the dynamodb is 100. So, I am not able to understand what does this value represent? How is this calculated from consumed read capacity metric? That is always less than 100 but even then I see some of the alarms.

Answer (score 1):

As the threshold mentions, we are considering breach of 5 datapoints within 5 minutes, meaning that each data point corresponds to 1 minute, i.e 60 seconds.

Now the `ReadCapacityUnits` are defined per second, which is 100 in your case. And the sum should be less than 60*100 = 6000 RCU per minute according to the alarm. That's how the figure `6000` came into the picture.